# Cache - disk or database?

Tags: php, mysql, caching, disk

Which is better on a shared host?

Do you think it's a good idea to cache database query results to disk?

Comment: caching database results to disk is "anti-caching".

Comment: Its a better idea to apply the caching engine on the outputted HTML, not on the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a very bad idea unless the queries are super-expensive (bad database layout?) *and* return a huge resultset.

- If the query is expensive but the resultset is small: Store it in memory, e.g. in memcached.
- If the query is cheap: Why cache it at all? But if you want to do it, memory is the way to go.

Databases usually keep lots of things in memory since disk access is very slow compared to memory access. So using the disk to cache small things usually doesn't increase the performance.

Comment: but the cheap host won't enable memcached :(

Comment: What you see is what you get.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the purpose. I'd store them in MemCache if it was available. Otherwise, storing them on disk is the best option I think.

But normally it is not necessary to store queries at all. Usually they will perform well. If you got queries this large and complex, you may be better off switching to a dedicated server. But before that, you might tweak our database by creating the right indexes and optimize your queries.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approuch:

I'm caching database querys on "disk" in a php array structure. Then mighty php opcode caching comes to work which giving me the results from memory instead from disk as they got cached. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator

Comment: I had this exact idea. Either I'm not crazy, or were both crazy! I have to do some benchmarks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not create of temporary table from the result maybe using a stored procedure and trigger? Storing to disk is a bit unusual.